# trigger.io android app launchimage prefs issue

Tags: android, trigger.io

Just finished first version of my trigger.io app, and successfully tested it on both android and ios platforms. (trigger.io v1.4, forge tools v3.3.11)

I have a minor glitch, however, which is : **I can't manage to change the android default trigger.io launch image.**

I set the proper image path in `App Config` panel, for both ios and android, but only ios version actually shows my image during application startup. Android version shows the trigger.io branded one.

Is there any format, color depth, or any undocumented characteristic of the image file that need to be known?

Investigation on my side :

- In `my app directory/development/android/res/drawable`, the `splash.png` file is trigger.io one. I don't know if i should expect to see my image file here.
- In the build process, i have the 5 lines of ios launchimages :

  ```
  {'do': {'copy_files': {'from': '${modules["launchimage"]["iphone"]}',
                      'to': 'development/ios/*.app/Default~iphone.png'}},
  ```

  but none for android launchimage values set in `App Config`
- `src/config.json` looks fine :

  ```
  "launchimage": {
      "android": "android.png", 
      "android-landscape": "android-landscape.png", 
      "ipad": "ipad.png", 
      "ipad-landscape": "ipad-landscape.png", 
      "ipad-landscape-retina": "ipad-landscape-retina.png", 
      "ipad-retina": "ipad-retina.png", 
      "iphone": "iphone.png", 
      "iphone-retina": "iphone-retina.png"
  },
  ```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Aurelien

Comment: What do you have in the launchimage section of your src/config.json (that's the file that App Config persists to)?

Comment: I added the launchimage section in the question

Comment: I also tried cleaning the app, rebuilding with default app config, but no without luck :/

Comment: Obvious question, but do android.png and android-landscape.png exist in your src directory? If that's not it, can you get in touch with support@trigger.io - sending us a zip of your src directory if possible - and we'll check the module's properly enabled for you and so on.

Comment: As stated in my email, found a way to reproduce the issue : just create a new app in trigger.io, set a launchimage for android, (works so far) then, set orientation to landscape in display config. Specified launchimage not displayed anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue - it was fixed in our v1.4.15 platform version: you'll pick that up automatically if you have v1.4 in your App Config.

Answer (score 1):

From the support email trail, it turned out the issue only occurs when specifying a landscape orientation with a launchimage. We have a ticket open in our backlog and will report back here when it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When I used a subfolder like img\loaderimage.png it didn't work. I moved the image to root and reconfigured the app then it worked.

Bug must be related with the \ sign or the builder is looking for the image in the root.