# trigger.io splashscreen for android

Tags: android, trigger.io

at the moment it is not possible to change the splashscreen for android. Everytime I change the launchimage settings in the config.json the old trigger.io splash will be shown. Btw, this works for iOS.

Afaik, hojoki also displays the trigger.io splashscreen ...

```
"launchimage": {
  "android": "img\\splash_320480.png",
  "android-landscape": "img\\splash_320480.png",
  "ipad": "img\\splash_320480.png",
  "ipad-landscape": "img\\splash_320480.png",
  "ipad-landscape-retina": "img\\splash_320480.png",
  "ipad-retina": "img\\splash_320480.png",
  "iphone": "img\\splash_320480.png",
  "iphone-retina": "img\\splash_320480.png"
}
```

Comment: Please post your launchimage config details.  http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/launchimage.html

Comment: "launchimage": {
   "android": "img\\splash_320480.png", 
   "android-landscape": "img\\splash_320480.png", 
   "ipad": "img\\splash_320480.png", 
   "ipad-landscape": "img\\splash_320480.png", 
   "ipad-landscape-retina": "img\\splash_320480.png", 
   "ipad-retina": "img\\splash_320480.png", 
   "iphone": "img\\splash_320480.png", 
   "iphone-retina": "img\\splash_320480.png"
  },

Comment: See Amir answer (trigger.io CEO) in my post about the same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250762/trigger-io-android-app-launchimage-prefs-issue

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed in our v1.4.15 platform version - you'll pick that up automatically if you have v1.4 in your App Config.

Answer (score 0):

if you put the images to the root it should work. i think there's a bug with the path resolving, it does not work with the subdirectories. (at least it was like that last time I tried)